# Why can't Tkinter open more than two windows?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working on a program in Python using Tkinter.

The issue is that I have buttons that open other windows. My issue is that it can't open more than two windows.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
from tkinter import *

class first(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.admin_btn = Button(master, text = "First", command = self.second)
        self.admin_btn.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        
    def second(self):
        self.w = second(self.master)
        self.master.wait_window(self.w.top)

class second(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        top = self.top = Toplevel(master)
        self.second = Button(top, text = "Second", command = self.third)
        self.second.grid(row= 0, column = 0)

    def third(self):
        self.w = third(self.master)
        self.master.wait_window(self.w.top)

class third(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        top = self.top = Toplevel(master)
        self.second = Button(top, text = "Third")
        self.second.grid(row= 0, column = 0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    m = first(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: run it in console/termina/cmd.exe/powershell and you see you get error message when you try to open third window

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that all your classes inherit from Toplevel instead of object, this way, all your classes will have a `master` attribute (which is why you had an error, the `second` class does not have one):

```
from tkinter import *

class First(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Toplevel.__init__(self, master)
        self.admin_btn = Button(self, text = "First", command = self.second)
        self.admin_btn.grid(row=0, column=0)

    def second(self):
        self.w = Second(self)
        self.wait_window(self.w)

class Second(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Toplevel.__init__(self, master)
        self.second = Button(self, text = "Second", command = self.third)
        self.second.grid(row=0, column=0)

    def third(self):
        self.w = Third(self.master)
        self.wait_window(self.w)

class Third(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Toplevel.__init__(self, master)
        self.second = Button(self, text = "Third")
        self.second.grid(row=0, column=0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    m = First(root)
    m.lift(root)
    root.wait_window(m)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot in second window

```
self.master = master
```

and you get error message when you try to open third window.

But you should rather assign `Toplevel(master)` to `self. master` and then use `self.master` instead of `self.top`

```
from tkinter import *


class First(object):

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master # = Tk()
        self.btn = Button(self.master, text="First", command=self.second)
        self.btn.grid(row=0, column=0)

    def second(self):
        self.w = Second(self.master)
        self.master.wait_window(self.w.master)


class Second(object):

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = Toplevel(master)
        self.btn = Button(self.master, text="Second", command=self.third)
        self.btn.grid(row=0, column=0)

    def third(self):
        self.w = Third(self.master)
        self.master.wait_window(self.w.master)


class Third(object):

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = Toplevel(master)
        self.btn = Button(self.master, text="Third")
        self.btn.grid(row=0, column=0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    first = First(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

And now all classes looks very similar - they have `self.master = Tk()` or `self.master = Toplevel(master)`

---

BTW: use `CamelCase` names for classes - `First`, `Second`, `Third` - it helps recognize classes in code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Demo1:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.button1 = tk.Button(self.frame, text = 'First', width = 25, command = self.new_window)
        self.button1.pack()
        self.frame.pack()
    def new_window(self):
        self.newWindow = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        self.app = Demo2(self.newWindow)

class Demo2:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.quitButton = tk.Button(self.frame, text = 'Second', width = 25, command = self.close_windows)
        self.quitButton.pack()
        self.frame.pack()
    def close_windows(self):
        self.master.destroy()

def main(): 
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Demo1(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In this code I have added two windows but you can add a third one.